# Is there any difference between using "content = { }" parameter or directly "{}" in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: parameters, android-jetpack-compose, parentheses, readability, curly-braces

I was wondering if it is better to use directly "content = {}" parameter instead of "{}" despite I see more often people using "{}".

Is the code cleaner or does the code load faster by using one or the other ?
Is there any good practice ?

When using "{}"

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
Box{}
}
```

When using "content = {}"

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
Box(content = {})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concepts used here are [Kotlin trailing lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas) and [Kotlin named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments).

**Kotlin named arguments**

So, this can be written with named arguments,

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
    Box({})
}
```

like this

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
    Box(content = {})
}
```

**Kotlin trailing lambda**

From the docs,

> According to Kotlin convention, if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses

This implies,

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
    Box({})
}
```

and

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
    Box() {}
}
```

are same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear. I am having a look on those different conventions.

Comment: @MisterPropre just something i would is if for exemple you created your own  function for exemple `fun MyCustomButton(text:String, onClick: ()->Unit)` then i would highly suggest instead of using**kotlin trailing lamda** use **kotlin named argument** because you may know that this lambda correspondence to `onClick` but another person that works in your team would not know that and they would have to look it up etc. This not a rule but a beat practice

Comment: Yes I will,. And frankly speaking, I kept that habit of always using Kotlin Named Argument. For a beginner like me, that way makes it very clear and useful. Thanks for your advice